# CASE WHEN Formula in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can you double check if I got my formula right? The the logic should be if the itemname is WEB, the QTYORDERED should be divided by 4 stacks

In my sample, I got an order which is only 1, but it is displaying 0 in result. :(

The correct result should be 0.25 right?

```
CASE
   WHEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.ItemNo = 'Web' 
      THEN ROUND(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4, 0)  
      ELSE dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered 
END AS NumberofItems
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the **datatype** of your `QtyOrdered` column? If it's `INT` - then you're performing an **integer division** (`QtyOrdered / 4`) and if the `QtyOrdered` value is 1, 2, or 3, this would result in **0**.

If you want your results to be with fractional values, you need to use a fractional dividend - like this:

```
CASE
   WHEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.ItemNo = 'Web' 
      THEN ROUND(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4.0, 0)  
      ELSE dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered         ^^^^
END AS NumberofItems
```

This would turn `QtyOrdered = 1` into 0.25, etc.